# DateTimeOffset Comparison not working

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I am trying to compare DateTimeOffset types. I am checking that the start date is not greater than the end date, but even when the start date is not greater than the end date it fails.

I debugged and hovered over this bit of code that is throwing the exception. The start value is 8/29/2013 and the end date is 9/1/2014.

Example Code:>

```
public IEnumerable<RecruitingPerformance> GetDailyRecruitingPerformance(DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset end, int? userId, int? projectId)
{
    if (end > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("End date must be today or before.", "end");
    }
    if (start > end)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Date must be greater than or equal to start", "end");
    }
```

Picture of trouble spot:>
[image]

Here is picture of the two objects for the non believers:
[image]

Comment: Did you check that the start and end date belong to the same time zone? This might be the issue...

Comment: @Brizio according to OP the start and end values are more than a year apart.

Comment: yeah they are plus on top of that they are in the same time zone -5:00

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I don't believe that DateTimeOffset is that broken...

Comment: Also, you might want to try to rebuild your project, as it might also be that you are debugging a different version.

Comment: I still think you are debugging an old version, as according to your code it should throw on the first if clause, not on the second.

Comment: @Brizio Perhaps he's posting this from the future? Have you considered that? I mean, Jon Skeet once posted an answer before the question was asked - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9135 - You never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the DateTimeOffset.Compare() method?

```
DateTimeOffset start = new DateTimeOffset(2013, 8, 29, 12, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0));
DateTimeOffset end = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 9, 1, 12, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0));

// if compare brings back 1, start is greater than end
if(DateTimeOffset.Compare(start, end) > 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Date must be greater than or equal to start", "end");
```

Comment: This doesn't really offer any significant difference than using the `>` operator...